# How to add custom property to Sprite object?

Tags: phaser-framework

I want to add custom property to my sprite object but when I try to get id property it returns "undefined". Is there a Phaser library bug or am I doing something wrong?

My update function;

```
function update() {
    //When I debug below line I can see enemyTank.tank.id property
    game.physics.arcade.overlap(enemyTank.tank, mytank.tank, enemyTankHitPlayer, null, this);
}
```

Callback function;

```
function enemyTankHitPlayer(myTankSprite, enemyTankSprite) {
    //enemyTankSprite.id is undefined!
}
```

Comment: I think we need more code, as I'm not seeing where you set the property nor where you query it.

Comment: Does mytank.tank have an id? If so try accessing that in the collision callback.

Comment: Also, you are passing in the tank and enemy tank in the opposite way around to what your callback. In the overlap function you pass enemyTank then mytank, but in the callback you pass myTank then enemyTank